# Unequal binary char comparison when MySQL string fetched from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I have some interesting issue. The following two codes do not produce the same output:

```
$result = $sql->QueryFetch("SELECT machinecodeSigned FROM ...");
echo bin2hex($result['machinecodeSigned']);
```

and

```
$result = $sql->QueryFetch("SELECT HEX(machinecodeSigned) FROM ...");
echo $result['machinecodeSigned'];
```

So, `$sql` is just some wrapper class and method `QueryFetch` internally just calls PHP standard functions for `query` and `fetch` to attain values.

I get two different results, though. For example, for some arbitrary input in my database, I get:

```
08c3bd79c3a0c2a66fc2bb375b6370c399c3acc3ba7bc2b8c2b203c39d70
```

and

```
08FD79E0A66FBB375B6370D9ECFA7BB8B203DD70
```

Ignoring case-sensitivity, the first output is nonsense while the other one is correct.

`machinecodeSigned` is a `char(255)` field that is `latin-1` encoded and has collation `latin-1` (which should not play a role, I assume).

What could be the reason that I get two different results? This `used to` yield the same results for years, but suddenly I had to change the code from version 1 to version 2 in order for it to produce the correct result. It seems, as if PHP does some arbitrary conversion of the bytes in the string.

Edit: It seems necessary to say that the field is not human-readable. In any case, since the second output is the correct one, feel free to convert the hexadecimal form to ASCII characters, if this helps you.

Edit:
`SHOW CREATE TABLE` yields:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
 `ID` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `machinecodeSigned` char(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin    DEFAULT NULL
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10092 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_german2_ci
```

Comment: @aa-Ahmed-aa How can such a comment get 3 upvotes? This is a binary char field, not human-readable, in which form would you like it? The second output is its hexadecimal form, do you want particular 0's and 1's or what are you asking here?

Comment: You said it is a char field encoded as a utf8 string using latin1 encoding, and now you're saying it is a binary data? Which is then? All of it contradicts itself IMO.

Comment: I think part of the confusion here is due to the fact that true binary data is normally stored in a BLOB field (or a related data type). You're storing it in a CHAR field, which for all intents and purposes, is human readable. Maybe you could explain a bit more about how the data goes in? Are you encoding it? As you've likely seen, there is a pattern between the first and second output, which indicates that, yes, PHP is receiving and converting unexpected bytes. You mentioned, `but suddenly I had to change the code...`, so I have to ask, what else has changed? Table schema? PHP version?

Comment: @waterloomatt I have not actively changed anything, my provider might have without my consent. I put data in the field by having binary code that I insert via something along `INSERT INTO table (machinecodeSigned) VALUES (X'hexedBinaryLoremIpsum')`
I clearly seem have made the mistake that I have not used a binary field which would have made more sense in retrospective... still, this system here does work for all values in my database (thousands of them), when I use the second version. But I see the confusion now

Comment: "calls PHP standard functions for query and fetch" -- Be more specific!  There is `mysql_*`, which should _not_ be used; there is `mysqli_*`; there is `PDO`.

Comment: `08FD79E0A66FBB375B6370D9ECFA7BB8B203DD70` does not make sense in any character set.  For Latin1, it is:  `ýyà¦o»7[cpÙìú{¸²Ýp`

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we will know the datatype of `machinecodeSigned`.

Comment: @IceFire - Neither HEX string in your Question is valid UTF-8.

Comment: @RickJames ok, phpmyadmin has shown UTF8 for the field, I have no clue why, but I have provided the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output now which seems to be more detailed/believable. And yes, your output is the one that I also get, which is why I said that the interpretation of this field is not human-readable. I have used the wrong data type here, it seems. Still, in works (in 2nd version)

Comment: @IceFire - After stripping off the leading BS (08), the utf8 interpretation of the first HEX is `ýyà¦o»7[cpÙìú{¸²Ýp`.  So, they probably agree with each other, but neither makes sense as "text".  I checked "file magic", but failed to find a likely 'magic' starting with 08.

Comment: @IceFire - phpmyadmin's utf8 is a default, and, I claim, incorrect for this text.  I  need to see the rest of the `SHOW`.

Comment: @RickJames Agreed, I do not want it to have text interpretation, this is why I did not want to provide it in the first instance. Still, why do I get different results here? Hexing a "binary" array is possible

Comment: @RickJames but it is complete

Comment: @IceFire - If the column is not "text", but is something "binary", such as an image, then the column should have datatype `BLOB` (or some variant of that).

Comment: @RickJames I have already agreed that I have chosen this data type poorly. As it works, I am still interested in why I get two different outputs

Comment: @IceFire - So is `machinecodeSigned` some kind of binary hash or checksum?  How was it computed?  How was it transmitted?

Comment: @RickJames yes, a stand-alone software creates it as a hash of some machine information. This is then signed with a public key provided by me. The result is binary and encoded with base64 to transmit it to my web server where it is base64-decoded and the inserted as written above with `VALUES(X'$machineCode')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin
```

will read/write bytes unchanged.  It would be better to say `BINARY(255)`, or perhaps something else.

If you tell the server that your *client* wants to talk in "utf8", and you `SELECT` that column, then MySQL will translate from latin1 (the charset of the data) to utf8 (the encoding you say the client wants).  This leads to the longer hex string.

You say that phpmyadmin says "utf8" somewhere; that is probably the cause of the confusion.

If it had been stored as base64, there would be no confusion because base64 uses very few different characters, and they are encoded identically in latin1 and utf8.  Furthermore, latin1_bin would have been appropriate.  So, another explanation of what went wrong is the unwanted reconversion from base64 to binary.

MySQL's implementation of latin1_bin is simple and permissive -- all 256 bit values are simply stored and loaded, unchecked.  This makes it virtually identical to `BLOB` and `BINARY`.

This is probably the base64_encode that should have been stored:

```
MDhGRDc5RTBBNjZGQkIzNzVCNjM3MEQ5RUNGQTdCQjhCMjAzREQ3MA==
```

Datatypes starting with `VAR` or ending with `BLOB` or `TEXT` are implemented via a 'length' field plus the bytes needed to represent the value.

On the other hand, `CHAR` and `BINARY` are fixed length, and padded by spaces (`CHAR`) or `\0` (`BINARY`).

So, writing binary info to `CHAR(255)` actually may modify the data due to spaces appended.

Comment: this makes perfect sense! I still wonder why this has never been a problem before. Maybe, characters of my `machinecodeSigned` were valid with `latin-1` in most of the cases? If I put some latin1 string in the field (which clearly has no special characters), my code above returns the same hex output in both cases (your edit makes this even more probable)

Comment: @IceFire - I added some more.

Comment: thank you! I wish I could give more upvotes to you. But would ‘\0’ not finish the string with char data type where it would not with binary?

Comment: @IceFire - I added 3 paragraphs to answer that question.